# Postfix unable to deliver to user's Maildir

Tags: email, postfix

Had a server that was using postfix/dovecot w/ CentOS 6.5/6.6,  Every thing has been running well for the past few months, until the raid controller failed.  So I installed a new server using CentOS 7. I i created the users using adduser (only a handle full fortunately) and copied the home directory contents including mail and set the owners the user:user and 770 permissions.

In each user's home folder is a Maildir directory that is set as:

```
drwxrwx--- 9 enduser postfix 4096 Nov 19 22:34 Maildir
```

All sub directories are 770 and files are 660.

The problem I am having is that Postfix is unable to write to the Maildir:

```
Nov 21 07:47:16 host postfix/local[12504]: warning: maildir access problem for UID/GID=1002/1002: create maildir file /home/enduser/Maildir/tmp/1416584836.P12504.host.domain.com: Permission denied
Nov 21 07:47:16 host postfix/local[12504]: 59E944726D1: to=<enduser@domain.com>, relay=local, delay=185, delays=185/0.02/0/0.05, dsn=5.2.0, status=bounced (maildir delivery failed: create maildir file /home/enduser/Maildir/tmp/1416584836.P12504.host.domain.com: Permission denied)
```

I've tried everything permission combination I can think of short of 777.

Any direction or light would be appreciated,

~ Wran

/home/enduser tree:

```
   .
    +-- enduser
        +-- Maildir
            +-- cur
            +-- new
            +-- tmp
```

Comment: maybe this help: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34233/how-to-create-maildir-directory-with-enough-permissions-for-postfix

Comment: Does the `Maildir` contain the appropriate subfolders (`cur`, `tmp` and `new`)?

Comment: @FedericoSierra SELinux is disabled (confirmed it just to make sure) and tried applying postfix as the group to the folders in /home.  Same error logged.

Comment: @JennyD Yup, the trees are fully intact.

Comment: Set ownership of the directory to the user. Eg `chown enduser:enduser /home/enduser/Maildir` and `chmod -R 700 /home/enduser/Maildir`

Comment: What are the permissions on `/home`?

Comment: @JennyD That's what the problem wasy /home was set to root:root 770, changed it to root:root 755 and it's delivering mail! Thank You!  Was a case of not seeing the forest through the trees.  Right problem, wrong location.

Comment: @Federico I tried those permissions initially but as Jenny suggested, the problem was at the /home directory level itself.

Comment: @Wranorn I rephrased it into an answer - it will be easier for other users who may face the same problem to find the answer that way. It'd be nice if you could accept it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order for mail to be delivered, postfix must be able to enter the user's home directory, and that directory must contain a complete Maildir tree containing the subfolders `tmp`, `cur` and `new`, all with the correct permissions.

Since you've already checked that the Maildir exists, has the correct folders, and has the right permissions, what remains is checking whether postfix (and the users themselves) can enter the users' home directory.

In order for that to work, the permissions have to be right every step of the way. So, not only does `/home/user` need to have the right permissions - so does `/home`. It must be set either to 750, if it's owned by a group that the users are members of, or 755 if it's not.

You can verify this by simply su'ing to a user and try to enter their home directory.

Answer (score 0):

looks like it is a regular directory,
`rm -rf /home/user/Maildir`
and POSTFIX will recreate the symlinks for you.

#### if you want manually to create it manually

```
 maildirmake.dovecot /etc/skel/Maildir
 maildirmake.dovecot /etc/skel/Maildir/.Drafts
 maildirmake.dovecot /etc/skel/Maildir/.Sent
 maildirmake.dovecot /etc/skel/Maildir/.Spam
 maildirmake.dovecot /etc/skel/Maildir/.Trash
 maildirmake.dovecot /etc/skel/Maildir/.Templates
 cp -r /etc/skel/Maildir /home/$mail_root_user/
 chown -R $mail_root_user:$mail_root_user /home/$mail_root_user/Maildir
 chmod -R 700 /home/$mail_root_user/Maildir
```

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Do you think it would be a good idea to backup before using `rm -rf` here? Or even could `mv` suffice?

Comment: of course backup if needed, well you got the idea. don't create a directory with mkdir instead if you really want to do it manually use `sudo maildirmake.dovecot /etc/skel/Maildir` but one second the error here that nothing could be delivered to this maildir ?? what exactly you want to backup @Paul!

Comment: We don't know what is in those directories, so instead of nuking them from orbit just get them out of the way.

Comment: The files already existed.  What you're suggesting doesn't solve the problem.  KEEPING the current mail in those directories.