# Postfix Maildir delivery failure due to read-only file system

Tags: email, postfix

Postfix fails to deliver messages with error "Read-only file system":

```
status=bounced (maildir delivery failed: create maildir file /home/deploy/Maildir/tmp/... : Read-only file system)
```

My directory permissions are set to 700 and 750 with owner set to deploy:deploy as suggested by this questions [Postfix unable to deliver to user's Maildir](https://serverfault.com/questions/646158/postfix-unable-to-deliver-to-users-maildir#646275).

```
    +-- /home/deploy: 700
        +-- Maildir: 750
            +-- cur: 750
            +-- new: 750
            +-- tmp: 750
```

Edit 1:

The output of `mount` is below. Everything is `rw` except `tmpfs`, which is `ro`:

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=240844k,nr_inodes=60211,mode=755)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=755)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_prio,net_cls)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuacct,cpu)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
/dev/vda1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=32,pgrp=1,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=50044k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
```

Edit 2:

`/home/deploy/Maildir/tmp/` is on `dev/vda1`:

```
$ df -h /home/deploy/Maildir/tmp
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1        20G  2.7G   16G  15% /
```

Edit 3:

Rebooting the server and running `dmesg -H` to see if there are any read/write or I/O errors. `dmesg -H` prints the following for `vda1`:

```
EXT4-fs (vda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
EXT4-fs (vda1): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
```

Edit 4:

The status of `SELinux` is disabled:

```
$ sestatus
SELinux status:                 disabled
```

The user `postfix` cannot write to `/home/deploy/Maildir/tmp/`:

```
$ sudo -H -u postfix bash -c 'pwd && touch test'
/home/deploy/Maildir/tmp
touch: cannot touch ‘test’: Permission denied
```

Comment: "read-only file system" is not related to the permission, it means, typically, that the filesystem encountered some errors and it was remounted read only to make sure problems do not propagate... Run the `mount` command to see the current status and have a look at your system logfile they should tell why and when the filesystem got remounted as read-only.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I updated my post to show the output of `mount`. Everything is mounted as `rw` except `tmpfs`.

Comment: Please add output of `df -h /home/deploy/Maildir/tmp/...` so it would show what device is underneath.

Comment: @kubanczyk it's on `/dev/vda1`

Comment: Check dmesg for IO errors. However it should affect all writes if this is the root filesystem

Comment: @eckes What am I looking for in particular with `dmesg`? I ran `dmesg -H` and did not find anything related to `/home/deploy/Maildir/tmp/..`

Comment: It should print something like „mounting Filesystem / read-only“ because of disk errors.

Comment: @eckes I updated the original post with Edit 3 printing everything for `/dev/vda1`. I didn't find anything along those lines.

Comment: try yourself as postfix user `touch /home/deploy/Maildir/tmp/foobar`, do you get any error message? Also, do you use SELinux ?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek The original post was updated to Edit 4 with your suggestions. SELinux is disabled, but `postfix` cannot write to the directory with a permission denied error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial error message seems misleading as with your latest edits we can clearly show that this is a permission problem.

From the own answer you link to:

> In order for mail to be delivered, postfix must be able to enter the user's home directory,

And you said:

> My directory permissions are set to 700 and 750 with owner set to deploy:deploy

But Postfix runs as user "postfix", so clearly no postfix process could enter `/home/deploy` which has permission `rwx-------` and owner/group `deploy:deploy`.

So you need to fix that.

If `/home/deploy` is only used for emails and nothing else (no user access to it), the simplest way would be to give ownership to user `postfix` for all files.

On the contrary if users access `/home/deploy` (I suppose a user called `deploy` and that you have many others under `/home`, but if you could it would be better to store user's email outside of their own directory if they are supposed to use it for other needs too), I would recommend something like:

```
/home/deploy deploy:postfix rwxr-x---
    Maildir postfix:postfix rwx------
        cur postfix:postfix rwx------
        new postfix:postfix rwx------
        tmp postfix:postfix rwx------
```

or

```
/home/deploy deploy:postfix rwxr-x---
     Maildir deploy:postfix rwxrwxs---
         cur deploy:postfix rwxrwxs---
         new deploy:postfix rwxrwxs---
         tmp deploy:postfix rwxrwxs---
```

(note the `s` as a big difference from above, to make sure all files are create with postfix group and hence readable/writable by it)

But it also depends if you want users to get, with their shell, access to Maildir or not. It also depends how email is picked up then, by some IMAP daemon maybe?

Another option is to configure Postfix to do the delivery with the user account UID, so that you have nothing to do regarding permissions. This depends on what MDA is used by Postfix.

Comment: I would also recommend to use /var/mail/deploy then you do not need to mess with parent directories and can use the group mail writeable for the actual user mailbox directory.